# Ajax com retorno tipo JSON multidimensional

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Salve, me buguei aqui tentando fazer o ajax me trazer uns dados de um JSON e eu preciso de uma aula/ajuda para entender como eu puxo os valores de um array de objetos(Acho que é isso rsrs).
Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, está meio confuso, mas o meu objetivo é fazer o seguinte:

- Campo "areaatu_02" foi selecionado?
- sim: Então retorna como "select" do html com os valores do "possui_titulo" que estão no JSON

só que eu nunca trabalhei com uma estrutura mais complexa de JSON, mexia com umas mais simplesinhas ex: { "nome": "Rafael Eduardo"}

Agora estou me deparando com array dentro de array e isso está bugando muito minha cabeça...

Ficou muito confuso a minha dúvida? segue abaixo o código que tentei criar:

json.php

```
 $obj = ('{
    "area_atuacao": [{
        "areaatu_02": [{
            "portador_titulo": [
                "AMB",
                "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
                ],
            "possui_titulo": [
                "MEDICINA PREVENTIVA E SOCIAL",
                "ADMINISTRACAO EM SAUDE" 
            ]
            }],
        "areaatu_04": [{
            "portador_titulo": [
                "AMB",
                "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
                ],
            "possui_titulo": [
            "ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA",
            "PEDIATRIA"
            ]
            }],
        "areaatu_07": [{
            "portador_titulo": [
                "AMB",
                "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
                ],
            "possui_titulo": [
            "ANGIOLOGIA",
            "CIRURGIA VASCULAR",
            "RADIOLOGIA"
            ]
            }]
    }]

}
');
// converto em um Array
    $myARRAY = json_decode($obj);
//coloco na tela
    echo json_encode($myARRAY);
    ?>
```

teste.php

```
        <select name="AREA_ATUACAO" class="form-control" id="areaAtu" onchange="areaAtuFun()">
                            <option value="erro" disabled="disabled" selected>-- Selecione uma opção --</option>
                            <option value="areaatu_01">ACUPUNTURA</option>
                            <option value="areaatu_02">ADMINISTRAÇÃO EM SAÚDE</option><!-- TEM REGRA -->
                            <option value="areaatu_03">ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA</option>
                            <option value="areaatu_04">ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA PEDIÁTRICA</option><!-- TEM REGRA -->
                            <option value="areaatu_05">ANESTESIOLOGIA</option>
            </select>
<div class='form-group col-md-4'>
<label for='PossueAreaAtu'>Portador do título de:</label>
<select name='PORTADOR_TITULO' class='form-control' id='PossueAreaAtu'>
<option value='erro' disabled='disabled' selected>-- Selecione uma opção --</option>
<span id="areaAtu_here"></span>
</select></div>


   <script>         
    function areaAtuFun() {

        var opFormValue = $('#areaAtu').val();
        var opFormUrl = "json.php?data=area_atuacao."+ opFormValue;

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: opFormUrl,
            method: "GET", 
            data: data,
            success: function(retorno){
                if (retorno.count != 0) {
                        $(retorno.area_atuacao).appendTo("#areaAtu_here")
                    }else{
                        alert("Deu ruim.")
                    }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Falha de conexão, tente novamente.")
            }
        })
                    var opForm = document.getElementById("areaAtu").value;
                    document.getElementById("areaAtu_here").innerHTML = "<option >"+ opForm +"</option>";
     }
```

Comment: O que queres colocar dentro de `.appendTo("#areaAtu_here")`?

Comment: @Sergio um `<option>` com o valor retornado pelo ajax... O `opForm` para ser mais preciso.

Comment: Mas o ajax retorna um objeto com uma array, queres um option para cada elemento da array? com que conteúdo? podes exempleficar esse(s) option(s)?

Comment: @Sergio imagina que eu selecionei o "areaatu_04" no meu `select id="areaAtu"`, quero que no `option` ele apareça as opções do `area_atuacao.areaatu_04.possui_titulo` que está no JSON, mais precisamente: `<option>ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA</option>` e `<option>ADMINISTRACAO EM SAUDE</option>`

Comment: Mas `ADMINISTRACAO EM SAUDE` é do `areaatu_02`... qual é a lógica dele aparecer? não seria `PEDIATRIA`?

Comment: @Sergio, é errei, não é areaatu_04 era o 2 mesmo, escrevi errado rsrs desculpa... mas a lógica é essa, aparecer as opções do que eu selecionar

Comment: Ok, e os option antigos desaparecem certo?

Comment: isso mesmo, correto!

Comment: Ok, e esse JSON tem mesmo de ter esse formato ou posso sugerir outro?

Comment: @Sergio pode sim cara, o meu está meio bugado rsrs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47891/discussion-between-sergio-and-ursones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma solução, que implica a mudança da estrutura do JSON (uma vez que disseste que isso era possivel). Dessa maneira fica mais simples, se não precisa de complicar melhor.

Estrutura do JSON:

```
{
    "areaatu_02": {
        "portador_titulo": [
            "AMB",
            "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
        ],
        "possui_titulo": [
            "MEDICINA PREVENTIVA E SOCIAL",
            "ADMINISTRACAO EM SAUDE"
        ]
    },
    "areaatu_04": {
        "portador_titulo": [
            "AMB",
            "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
        ],
        "possui_titulo": [
            "ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA",
            "PEDIATRIA"
        ]
    },
    "areaatu_07": {
        "portador_titulo": [
            "AMB",
            "RESIDÊNCIA MÉDICA"
        ],
        "possui_titulo": [
            "ANGIOLOGIA",
            "CIRURGIA VASCULAR",
            "RADIOLOGIA"
        ]
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
function areaAtuFun() {

    var opFormValue = $('#areaAtu').val();
    var tituloSelect = $('#PossueAreaAtu');
    var opFormUrl = "json.php?data=area_atuacao." + opFormValue;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: opFormUrl,
        method: "GET",
        success: function(retorno) {
            var valores = retorno[opFormValue].possui_titulo;
            if (valores.length == 0) return alert('Houve um erro com os dados! 0');
            $('#PossueAreaAtu option').remove(); // apagar as options existentes
            valores.forEach(function(string) {
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: string,
                    html: string
                }).appendTo(tituloSelect);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Falha de conexão, tente novamente. 1")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Bem mais simples do que eu pensava!, muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar o JSON em Array, você precisa indicar o `true` dentro do `json_decode`

**Ficando assim:**

```
$myARRAY = json_decode($obj, true);
```

E para pegar os dados em PHP basta tentar:

```
$myARRAY['area_atuacao']['areaatu_04']['...'];
```